# How to fix typings deprecated warnings

Tags: typescript, npm, asp.net-core, typescript-typings

When I run

```
npm install
```

I get dozens of these errors.

```
typings WARN deprecated 9/9/2016: "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160831021119" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
```

I'm new to  typescript and the whole thing has been a mess of errors for weeks just trying to  get a sample site from lesson going.

My `typings.json` is :

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654"
  },
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160831021119",
    "body-parser": "registry:dt/body-parser#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "compression": "registry:dt/compression#0.0.0+20160501162003",
    "cookie-parser": "registry:dt/cookie-parser#1.3.4+20160316155526",
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20160317120654",
    "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#0.0.0+20160322035842",
    "mime": "registry:dt/mime#0.0.0+20160316155526",
    "serve-static": "registry:dt/serve-static#0.0.0+20160317120654"
  }
}
```

Also  where do  I find those registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+2........ numbers and do  they REALLY keep changing/updating.?
How do  I keep things going longer than a few days without errors.?

I now have 17,769 Files in a project without a single webpage?????

Answer (score 4):

Today you can actually [use TypeScript without Typings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).
To get the definitions listed above, just install them from `@types` user in NPM.

`npm install --save @types/core-js @types/jasmine @types/node @types/body-parser`
etc.

It is a good habit to install both the package and it's typings.
E.g. `npm i -S express @types/express`, `npm i -S jasmine @types/jasmine`

`npm i -S` is synonymous to `npm install --save`

Comment: And if you don't want to do it that way, just remove the line from your `typings.json` file, and reinstall with `typings`...i.e. remove the `dt/jasmine` line and run `typings install dt~jasmine` to get the latest version

Comment: Thanks. That got rid of one configuration file at least.

Still getting these various errors when I run above npm install --save @types/core-js etc

UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@1.8.10

My devDependencies seems fine so  not sure what to  do about error.

 "devDependencies": {
    "del": "2.1.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.4",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "merge": "1.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  },