# How to get the later/latest version of a package of registry:dt/core-js?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have *typings.json* like this.

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.9.7+20161130133742"
  }
}
```

Can't say that I'm certain what it means but when I reinstall (recreating *typings* directory), I'm getting the following message.

> 2017-03-10: "registry:dt/core-js#0.9.7+20161130133742" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)

As far my understanding goes, it means that the specifiv revision (i.e. 20161130133742) of the specific version (i.e. 0.9.7) is outdated and should be upgraded to the lastest version. However, when I went to [the NPM site of the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js), it says there's no documentation about it and the version says 2.4.1. Then, I realized that in my *pacakge.json* I have that specific version already.

I tried to remove everything after the sharpie, i.e. *"core-js": "registry:dt/core-js"* but it only produced hundreds of error in regard to my typings.

Now, I'm confused - how do I update the global dependencies in *typings.json* to the latest version? And, also, shouldn't I have a line with *node* as well?

Googling for the most of today gave me mostly confusion and headache so I'm totally lost and need to regain my bearings. However, I do recall something like the following.

```
"node": "registry:dt/node"...
```

Should that be inserted as well? I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39491733/1525840) that I don't even need the file to begin with. Is that correct?

My config is Webpack 2.0, Node 7.0, NPM 3.10 and TS 2.2 trying to target Angular.